# How to access Main Application from alternate entry point on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my app, I have used one alternate entry point to check time.
If smartphone go to the time I set here, it will push one screen (ex Screen1) in my main app.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
    if ( args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("autorun") ) {
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();  
    } else {    
        theApp.pushScreen(new MyScreen());
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
}
```

in Screen1 have some button (ex New button), generally when I run my app and click "New button" , it will push Screen2. but in this case, no thing occur. 
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What is the "autorun" entry point for? It doesn' push any screen.

Answer (score 4):

**Using the BlackBerry® Java® Plug-in for Eclipse®**

After creating the project for the original application,

- create an alternate entry point to launch the application UI.
- Double click on BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml within your project.
- Check off **System Module** and **Do not display the application icon** on the BlackBerry home screen.
- Click on the **Alternate Entry Point** tab.
- Click the **Add...** button.
- Enter a title for the entry point and click **OK**.
- Specify the application argument that would launch the application using this alternate entry point (for example: `gui`).
- Proceed to the **Common Steps** section.

for Moreinfo:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Set-up-an-alternate-entry-point-for-an-application/ta-p/444847

Comment: Yes I did that . You do not understand my question. Example in my UI App, i have 2 screen Screen1 and Screen2. In Screen 1 have " New button " to push Screen 2. but when I push Screen 1 from alternate entry point, "New Button" no effect , I click :New button " and it do not display Screen 2.