# Generate alx file that refer to two cod files

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have an application that receives push notifications and it registers for push notifications in a background app.  The background app is configured as an alternate entry point.

So in all I have two applications and I want to create an alx file that can reference both applications. I want my deployed ALX to to register for push notifications with my server in the background and when I touch the app icon, it should start the normal UI functionality.

I am using BlackBerry jde for development.

Comment: First thing, there is no two applications. If you create an alternate entry point, it will run in background and the UI application will run when you click the app icon.

Comment: @signare yes that happens currently but the problem is that when I click the application on device it asks for some permissions when I click it hangs because background application starts run and it looks as if device hangs not sure but does that makes any sence

Comment: that is the problem of setting the alternate entry point

Comment: refer this for creating alternate entry point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921029/how-to-setup-alternate-entry-point-in-blackberry-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265919/how-to-access-main-application-from-alternate-entry-point-on-blackberry

Comment: Thanks for help @Signare i have one more doubt if the task that we do in background requires some permissions to run or say application needs some permissions then will our device still run the app in background

Comment: The process will be paused in the instruction that needs permission until the user closes the permissions dialog. If the user accepts it, it continues. Else a `ControlledAccessException` exception will be thrown.

Comment: @MisterSmith the problem is that when I close the permission dialog the device hangs It might be due to background process running !! does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730580/generate-alx-file-that-refer-to-two-cod-files#comment20609060_14730580) comment it seems your problems concern permissions and not bundling. Check these links for an idea on how to invoke a permissions request before doing anything.

- [API reference - ApplicationPermissions class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissions.html)
- [How to - Invoke a Permissions request with other applications also requesting permissions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Invoke-a-Permissions-request-with-other-applications-also/ta-p/652397)

The first link also has some sample code.